# How to change ListTile leading icon color in ThemeData() on FLutter

Tags: flutter

I have a list tile widget and the color of the leading icon is set to default for both light and dark theme in flutter.

After upgrading flutter to Flutter 2.5.1, the list tile leading icon is weird in dark mode.

I have to change the leading icon color to white in the dark mode and default in the light mode and this has to be changed in the Theme Data manually.

[image]

My Theme class

```
  static ThemeData myTheme(bool isDark) {
    return !isDark
        ? ThemeData.light().copyWith(
            primaryColor: Colors.deepPurple,
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(
              secondary: Colors.deepPurple,
            ),
          )
        : ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
            primaryColor: Colors.deepPurple,
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(
              secondary: Colors.deepPurple,
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To apply color to icons in ListTiles across the entire app you should define iconColor in listTileTheme

```
ThemeData(
  listTileTheme: const ListTileThemeData(
    iconColor: Colors.purple
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
           return MaterialApp(
              themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
              theme: ThemeData(
                iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.blue),
              ),
              darkTheme: ThemeData(
                iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.red),
              ));
```

Comment: I tried, but still have the problem, are you sure the icon you tested was in a ListTile?